# Add multiple UIImage copies using UIStepper

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, uistepper

I want to add/delete images in a view using a UIStepper. So every time you press the '+' the same image is copied within the same viewController, still being able to move/rotate every copy.

I have something like this:

```
- (IBAction)ValueChanged:(UIStepper *)value
{
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    int j = (int) value.value;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < j ; ++i )
    {
        UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        newImageView.image = self.myImageView.image;
        [imageArray addObject:newImageView];
        [self.view addSubview:imageArray[i]];
    }
}
```

but this does not work because it just replaces the previous image.

Is there a proper way to copy the same image multiple times using the UIStepper?

Comment: Specify the frame, it is not replacing, new image view hides the previous one.

Comment: So far so good, the images are added properly but when adding the images don't stay on their current position when touching the '+'. And I'm only able to move one image around with the pan gesture.

Comment: Are you sure the frame have the correct origin? They could be overlapping if the all are located in (0,0)